# Using 'order' with 'limit' in an objectify query

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I want to do a query that gets the 16 entities with highest value in one field, so I've tried variations on this query:

```
ofy().load().type(MyEntityClass.class).order("addTime").limit(16).list();
```

This produces a null set.  When I remove 'order' I get 16 entities, but they appear to be randomly selected (as would be expected).

Is it not possible to use order, limit, and list like this?

Does the field specified in 'order' need to be indexed?  Looking at the datastore API for 'addSort' it appears this is not a requirement.

And BTW, I could find documentation for 'order' because the ['API javadoc' site](http://www.javadochub.com/doc/com.googlecode.objectify/objectify) at javadochub.com is down.  Is it available elsewhere?

Comment: After a quick email, the javadoc is available again. Apparently javadochub.com moved to javadoc.io and the redirector broke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort order can only be set on an indexed property.

> A query can't find property values that aren't indexed, nor can it
>   sort on such properties.

From: [Restrictions on queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Restrictions_on_queries)